# Prevent rollback in retry in Spring Batch

Tags: spring, spring-batch, batch-processing, rollback, spring-retry

How is it possible to prevent a step to be rolled back after a retry exception is thrown?
When i set the exception as `norollback` , an exception is thrown and says that  the exception that has no rollback must be set as skippable but i dont want it to be skipped.

Comment: Please provide your configuration